# View details of event when mouseover in moss (sharepoint) calendar web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, calendar, hover, mouseover

In Moss Calendar webpart, is there any way that I can see some of the details of an event when I hover over a specific event with my mouse without actually entering that event?

Thanks in advance!

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is mainly theory as I have not tried it before.

Since a calendar webpart is really nothing more than a SharePoint List I would suggest you use JQuery to determine the list item that you are hovering over on your calendar webpart, then fire an ajax call the the [SharePoint List Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001568/accessing-sharepoint-tasks-via-web-services/3001811#3001811) via JQuery to retrieve additional information about that list item and display it in a popup window or JQuery UI Dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's actually what I did, I found the answer here:http://www.edugeek.net/forums/how-do-you-do/64167-sharepoint-2010-calendars.html